# method with return type List<int,string>

Tags: c#, list

How can I create a method GetStudents() It will return list of all students.
Where the return type of GetStudents() is List where int= id and string= name?

The method needs to be created in visual studio.

Comment: You could return either a Dictionary<int, string> (assuming the Ids are unique) or a List<Tuple<int, string>>. However, instead of doing that, define a proper Student type and return a list of that.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram you mean to say public static List<Student> GetStudents() instead of  public static List<Tuple<int, string>> GetStudent( ) ?

Comment: Yes, that is my suggestion.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram what if I uses List<Tuple<int, string>> GetStudent( )  how will I return the list of all students from database??

Answer (score 0):

Several ways:

- Create a class named `Student` with two public properties `id` and `name` and then use `List<Student>` as return type.

  ```
  class Student
  {
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
  }

  public List<Student> GetStudents()...
  ```
- Use `Tuple<int, string>`

  ```
  public List<Tuple<int, string>> GetStudents()...
  ```
- Use new C# syntax that allows writing return types like `(int, string)`.

  ```
  public List<(int id, string name)> GetStudents()... //works in C# 7
  ```
- Use `Dictionary<int, string>` as return type.

  ```
  public Dictionary<int, string> GetStudents()... //IDs must be unique
  ```

Comment: I'm not sure 3 applies in this case - how can you use it to return a `List<(int, string)>`?

Comment: @DStanley: Haven't tried it, but I thought `(int, string)` is just a shorthand for `Tuple<int, string>`.

Comment: Conceptually, it's similar, but I don't think you can replace `List<Tuple<int, string>>` with `List<(int, string)>`.

Comment: @dotNET I applied the third one before getting here it is not applicable it generates errors

Comment: @dotNET (int, string) is a struct of type ValueTuple, and because of that is a value type. Tuple<int,string> is a class and by that, a reference type.

Comment: @SaniyaKaleem What kind of erros? it's a new feature on C#7, and if you don't target .Net 4.7, you have to import the ValueTuple reference from the nuget

Comment: @Magnetron: Thanks for pointing out. However C# does allow List of value types, so `List<ValueTuple>` should have been possible, no?

Comment: @dotNET yes, it's possible, my comment was just to point out that it's not a shorthand

Comment: @Magnetron i am targeting .Net 4.6 maybe that is the reason?

Comment: @SaniyaKaleem yes, that's probably. If you want to keep it, you have to get this package to work: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/ .Also, since it's C#7, you probably have to use VS2017. I tried with VS2015 and I got an error

Comment: @Magnetron        Yes i got that i am using VS2015 so even after having the package i am getting an error